# Is System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll supported in the beta release of windows phone 7 series?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does windows phone 7 series support the System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at building an application or two on the Windows Phone 7 to interface with RESTful services, you may look at [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/), which now supports Windows Phone 7. [Luke Lowrey's article](http://lukencode.com/2010/08/04/rest-web-services-in-windows-phone-7/) is a good starting point on using RESTSharp in Windows Phone 7. In [this article](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/14/google-weather-api-with-restsharp/), Luke shows how he uses RESTSharp to consume the Google Weather XML feed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Silverlight 3 version of System.ServiceModel.Syndication from the Silverlight 3 SDK should work on Windows Phone but is not officially supported. It may support the features you need from the .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm pretty sure for now if you want to parse feeds you just have to use Xml.